# Why no response from Blockchain websocket API?

Tags: javascript, api, websocket, bitcoin

Im having a problem with my websocket connection.
(like you probably understand, I want to get a notification when the address gets a transaction, and so on...)

Im not a "superstar" when it comes to javascript, but in my head and from what I read, this should work.

The websocket seem to be open and working, because when I send "op": "blocks_sub" instead of the address, I get the Unconfirmed transactions, and so on...

I would be MORE than grateful if someone could point me in the right direktion of this headache of mine...

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>WebSocket</title>

<h1>WebSocket</h1>

<div id="output" style="font-size: x-large; color: blueviolet;">
    output go here ...
</div>
<br>

<script>
    $bitcoin_address = "bc1qcg3x50m3785la5qc5tqe2z8htutcn8deyjvc8u";

    var btcs = new WebSocket("wss://ws.blockchain.info/inv");

    btcs.onopen = function() {
        btcs.send(JSON.stringify({
            // "op": "blocks_sub"
            "op": "addr_sub",
            "addr": "$bitcoin_address"
        }));
    };

    btcs.onmessage = function(onmsg) {
        var response = JSON.parse(onmsg.data);
        var amount = response.x.out[0].value;
        var calAmount = amount / 100000000;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = calAmount + "btc";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What does the blockchain.info documentation state about how you'll get what notifications when…?

Comment: `"$bitcoin_address"` That's not how template literal works and it's not needed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There were no transactions related to this address. Last transaction with the address `bc1qcg3x50m3785la5qc5tqe2z8htutcn8deyjvc8u` occurred @ `2022-01-20 20:09 UTC`i.e.~ 11 hours ago.
Probably you subscribed later.

Comment: Yes, that’s the latest transaction I made, to se if it works. But I did ent get the notification on the page I was hoping for.

Comment: Did you make this transaction while your program was listening to websocket?

Comment: Try `{ "op": "ping_tx }"` after subscribing to see if you can the latest transaction. for this address.

Comment: Yes. I hade the page open (the above code) while I did the transaction.
plus this line in my "onopen function": document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Connected";

and the DIV (output) said Connected

Comment: Did you do this *before* making a transaction?

Comment: You got balance? It should be last transaction.

Comment: Then, probably, you have an error in the address encoding. Try to `console.log` your json and check it.

Comment: Also try `"addr": $bitcoin_address`

Comment: No errors shown in the console, and same “no answer” with or without “”. I’m really confused, because the socket are clearly open, and I send in exactly what the blockchain Doc. say??? Is it something I miss??